# dspace AIP package restore throws exception

Tags: dspace

I was trying to restore the DSpace site (sitewide) using AIP restore. The system threw some errors, as described in the screenshot

[image]

I am using dspace version 6.2

Following is the stripped parts of the executed commands

```
./dspace packager -r -a -f -t AIP -e abcd@gmail.com -i 123456789/0 -o skipIfParentMissing=true /build/bkpJune2023/sitewide-aip-10Jun2023.zip

at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:81)
Caused by: org.dspace.content.packager.PackageException: Unable to translate Handle to Internal ID in group named 'COLLECTION_hdl:123456789/299_SUBMIT' as DSpace Object (Handle='hdl:123456789/299') does not exist.
    at org.dspace.content.packager.PackageUtils.translateGroupNameForImport(PackageUtils.java:944)
    at org.dspace.content.crosswalk.METSRightsCrosswalk.ingest(METSRightsCrosswalk.java:537)
    ... 16 more
org.dspace.content.crosswalk.CrosswalkException: org.dspace.content.packager.PackageException: Unable to translate Handle to Internal ID in group named 'COLLECTION_hdl:123456789/299_SUBMIT' as DSpace Object (Handle='hdl:123456789/299') does not exist.
```

It seems some of the items are unable to be restored. Is there any way to skip this? I have already used a parameter skipIfParentMissing=true